# Can an actor return an object to a future waiting on an ask?

Tags: scala, akka

I would like to use an actor to synchronize access to a pool of objects. The actor would manage the objects in the pool including their state (busy v.s. free to allocate). When `ask`ed by non-actor code, it would return an object from the pool once available. Thus the calling code has an abstraction for obtaining an object to work with.

To get this kind of abstraction, I need the actor to be able to respond to its message senders' `ask` messages with the object the actor is allocating to them. Can this be accomplished and would it be resource intensive to pass a whole object via a message?

Comment: Why cant it happen? Its like normal akka message passing.

Comment: Is it legit to pass back an entire object?

Comment: Assuming both actors are local, you can pass whatever you want.  If remoting is involved the object has to be serializable.  Also, be extremely careful if the object isn't immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in returning future that will be completed later, by actor.

Keep an eye on this matter, however: will you complete the future with some mutable internal actor state or not?

If the answer is no - it is ok and there is nothing you should worry about.

If the answer is yes - you'll have to take care of synchronization, since actor/external code may mutate this state in different threads (which, kind of defeats the purpose of using actors).

Otherwise it is legit.

BTW, this is not something that is specific to futures only. You have to follow this for any message you send from actor.

---

**UPDATE**: extending my answer to address OP's comment.

> Question was primarily about returning an object that's not an actor, from an actor, not just about the scenario... not sure if this answer relates to just that... an object can be much heavier than just a "regular" message... unless Akka passes a message in a way equivalent to a reference / interning.

There is no special requirements about "heaviness" of the message in akka and in general it can be any object (you can infer this from the fact that `Any` is used for the type of the message instead of some akka-defined message class/trait with set of defined limitations).

Of course, you have to treat specially situations when messages should be persisted or sent to remote host, but this is kind of special case. In this scenario you have to ensure that serialization is handled properly.

Anyway, if the message (object) does not leave boundaries of the same jvm - it is ok for object to hold any amount of state.

Comment: Question was primarily about returning an object that's not an actor, from an actor, not just about the scenario... not sure if this answer relates to just that... an object can be much heavier than just a "regular" message... unless Akka passes a message in a way equivalent to a reference / interning.

Comment: thank you very much!
I think however it depends on how Akka moves messages around within the same JVM though. If it first serializes them, then I think sending over a whole object may be quite bad for performance. Serializing and then unserializing a whole object is quite intensive. If it only presents a reference to an object held in memory, that's better. So I'm still a bit undecided...

Comment: @matt by default no serialization is used. You can enforce it for testing purposes (read: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/serialization.html#Verification) but generally messages are passed "by reference" (again, with exception of remoting/persiste, and possibly some other special cases).